# Why are the characters are doubled up (uupp) when written to the file?

Tags: c, file-io

I have made (nearly) a program which prints the complete line into the file (unless you press enter); please have a look at it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void getline ( FILE *filep){
    char c;int word = 100,lenmax=100;
    char *line = (char *)malloc (100),*exline,*save = line;
    printf("enter the data to be written press only enter at the end of the paragraph\n");
    while(1){
        c = fgetc ( stdin );

        if ( --word != 0){
            *line++ = c;
        }
        else{
            word = 100;
            exline = realloc(save ,lenmax += 100);
            if (exline == NULL){
                free ( line);
                exit(1);
            }
            line = exline + (lenmax-100);
        }

        if ( (*line++=c)=='\n'){
            *line = '\0';
            break;
        }

    }
    fprintf(filep,"%s",save);
    free(line);
    free(exline);
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("beauty.txt","w");
    getline(fp);
    return 1;
 }
```

**PROBLEM** if, for example, you write "hello world i am here", at console it will be printed on file like this:

```
hheelloo wwoorrlldd ii aamm hheerree
```

means each character two times. Please figure out the error. I am very much confused. Also tell me is it necessary to free both pointer namely `line` and `exline`? Isn't it okay only with this

```
free(exline);//as exline is pointing to the complete buffer
```

Comment: You sure like to do things as complicated as possible, huh?

Comment: I suggest stepping through with a debugger and watching what you're doing...

Comment: @Wooble i did but it doesn't helped!

Comment: Please: You never free a pointer, you free a block of memory you allocated. Don't forget any, and never free twice.

Comment: Beware: POSIX defines a function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) with a radically different interface from yours, which could cause you problems.

Answer (score 2):

You do first

```
if ( --word != 0){
    *line++ = c;
}
```

and then

```
if ( (*line++=c)=='\n'){
    *line = '\0';
    break;
}
```

which is putting the character twice into `line`.

Don't free both `line` and `exline`, because when you [`realloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), `line` is not valid anymore.
Furthermore, `exline` might not be initialized at all, as long as you remain below 100 characters.
And finally, you modify `line` while reading characters, so it isn't a valid heap pointer anyway. You can save the variable `save` and just use `exline`. So the correct way could be

```
char *line = malloc (100), *exline = line;
/* ... */
save = exline;
exline = realloc(save, lenmax += 100);
if (exline == NULL) {
    free(save);

/* ... */
free(exline);
```

This would also fix additional `realloc`ations beyond the first 100 characters.

Comment: thanxx man i just figured it.but what about my second question about free()?

Comment: now i have corrected it but still when i enter more than 100 chars program crashes please figure it out?

Comment: exline=realloc (exline,lenmax += 100) is dangerous as if realloc() fails than it will return NULL and which is assigned to exline and causes memory leak.isn't it?

Comment: The leak does not matter, as you immediately call `exit()` if the allocation fails. Regarding `free()`: Just free any block of memory you allocate, but only once (unless you exit immediately, then don't bother).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. See updated answer, if you really need to take care of memory (i.e. don't exit).